# What is the screen of a microwave made off?

Tags: materials

What material is the viewing screen of a microwave made of?  I have been researching and all I find is that the holes on the screen are too small to let the bulky microwave radiation to pass through.

Comment: How much looking did you do?  It seems like you already have the answer: glass to see through and metal (mesh) with small holes. Is there something else that you are having trouble with?

Comment: intersting patent from 1974 US 3808391 A, apparently they planned on having just a perforated metal window with no glass (to let fumes escape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shielding in a microwave must be an electrically conductive material (usually thin steel), because it reflects microwaves.

The viewing window is also made of an electrically conductive material (thin steel), but has holes cut in it that are large enough to permit shorter wavelengths like light to pass through (so we can view it), but reflects long wavelengths like microwaves.

[Microwave Oven Design on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Design)